# Django-Aws error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, compiler-errors

When I use fab spawn instance I get the following error. Can anybody help me out? fabfile/django_fabric_aws.py", line 179, in _create_ec2_instance     image = conn.get_all_images(ec2_amis).AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_all_images'

Comment: The error message is self explainatory. your conn object is None.

Comment: Have you set fabconf['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'] in project_conf.py ?

Comment: The problem is solved. When I changed few parameters in django_fabric_aws.py. file everything worked. Thanks.

Comment: Great! You could answer your own question and mark it as answered so next time anyone else encounters the same problem they know what to do.